# The Word Chain!

Tags: language

You must create a sentence that is grammatically correct, each word must begin with the last letter in the word before. The first word must start with the last letter of the last word. This sentence must be at least 4 words long.

Comment: Is there a way you can think of to limit the scope of the answers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My yacht, tied down near Richard's, seemed drab because Ethel lost the emblem.

So our restaurant tried doing gnocchi in new ways.

Reading Graham's sentences should delight the enquirer.

Comment: Nice work! Did you enjoy the puzzle?

Comment: Yes, the final link back to the start made it challenging.

Comment: Well you managed to create 3 so you did really well!

Comment: Ethel has always been a disappointment.